# Replace string between two time values

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, webvtt

I am trying to clean up broken VTT files, where the lines show:
`00:00.000 -- constituent 00:06.880` but instead should show
`00:00.000 --> 00:06.880`

VTT is written so that it's MM:SS:MSMSMS, and minutes can be any value, so I tried to match that via a regexp using `^\d+\:\d+\.\d+$`, which apparently should work and on some regexp testing places it matches at first, but then when I add additional content to the string the match fails.

How can I get the string between these two matches so that I can replace it with `-->` ? The word here (`constituent`) is variable and so I need a general regexp rather than just a match and replace for the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex and replace code:

```js
const input = `
1
00:00.000 -- constituent 00:06.880

2
00:30.022 test-test 00:37.750`;

const result = input.replace(/^(\d[\d:.]+\d)\b.*?\b(\d[\d:.]+\d)$/gm, "$1 --> $2");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The only issue that is there's no guarantee that it will come in the format of `-- word` , so I was hoping to just match anything within those two time values and replace with ` --> `

Comment: Do you mean the `--` may not be there either?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `^(\d+[\d:.]+\d+)([-a-z\s]+)(\d+[\d:.]+\d+)$`

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/2nLCut/1

Groups 1 and 3 are the times, and 2 is the captured variable (this means you can replace the entire match with group 1 and group 3 to eliminate the string in group 2)